# Labelling and Grouping Postcodes using Python

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to Python and I am attempting to group various postcodes together under predefined labels. For example "SA31" would be labelled a "HywelDDAPostcode"

I have some code where I read lots of postcodes from a singled columned file into a list and compare them with postcodes that are in predefined lists. However, when I output my postcode labels only the Label "UKPostcodes" is outputted for every postcode in my original file. It would appear that the first two conditions in my code always evaluate to false no matter what. Am I doing the right thing using "in"? Or perhaps it's a file reading issue? I'm not sure

The input file is simply a file which contains a list of postcodes ( in reality it has thousands of rows)

[The CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI8oK.png)

Here is my code:

```
import csv

with open('postcodes.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)

my_list =[]
HywelDDAPostcodes=["SA46","SY23","SY24","SA18","SA16","SA43","SA31","SA65","SA61","SA62","SA17","SA48","SA40","SA19","SA20","SA44","SA15","SA14","SA73","SA32","SA67","SA45",
     "SA38","SA42","SA41","SA72","SA71","SA69","SA68","SA33","SA70","SY25","SA34","LL40","LL42","LL36","SY18","SY17","SY20","SY16","LD6"]

NationalPostcodes=["LL58","LL59","LL60","LL61","LL62","LL63","LL64","LL65","LL66","LL67","LL68","LL69","LL70","LL71","LL72","LL73","LL74","LL75","LL76","LL77","LL78",
                 "NP1","NP2","NP23","NP3","CF31","CF32","CF33","CF34","CF35","CF36","CF3","CF46","CF81","CF82","CF83","SA35","SA39","SA4","SA47","LL16","LL18","LL21","LL22","LL24","LL25","LL26","LL27","LL28","LL29","LL30","LL31","LL32","LL33","LL34","LL57","CH7","LL11","LL15","LL16","LL17","LL18","LL19","LL20","LL21","LL22","CH1","CH4","CH5","CH6","CH7","LL12","CF1","CF32","CF35","CF5","CF61","CF62","CF63","CF64","CF71","LL23","LL37","LL38","LL39","LL41","LL43","LL44","LL45","LL46","LL47","LL48","LL49","LL51","LL52","LL53","LL54","LL55","LL56","LL57","CF46","CF47","CF48","NP4","NP5","NP6","NP7","SA10","SA11","SA12","SA13","SA8","CF3","NP10","NP19","NP20","NP9","SA36","SA37","SA63","SA64","SA66","CF44","CF48","HR3","HR5","LD1","LD2","LD3","LD4","LD5","LD7","LD8","NP8","SY10","SY15","SY19","SY21","SY22","SY5","CF37","CF38","CF39","CF4","CF40","CF41","CF42","CF43","CF45","CF72","SA1","SA2","SA3","SA4","SA5","SA6","SA7","SA1","NP4","NP44","NP6","LL13","LL14","SY13","SY14"]


NationalPostcodes2= list(dict.fromkeys(NationalPostcodes))
labels=["HywelDDA","NationalPostcodes","UKPostcodes"]

for postcode in your_list:
    #print(postcode)
    if postcode in HywelDDAPostcodes:
        my_list.append(labels[0])
    if postcode in NationalPostcodes2:
        my_list.append(labels[1])
    else:
        my_list.append(labels[2])

with open('DiscretisedPostcodes.csv','w') as result_file:
    wr = csv.writer(result_file, dialect='excel')
    for item in my_list:
     wr.writerow([item,])
```

If anyone has any advice as to what could be causing the issue or just any advice surrounding Python, in general, I would very much appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. The main problem is you haven't provided the input file, but also those lists are unreadably long, and outputting to a file seems to be irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Without seeing your input file its hard to tell, but `if postcode in ...` should work properly, my bet the reading and parsing of the file causes the error

Comment: Thank for your replies, apologies for not including the file and not making the post more readable. I have now included the file although I'm not sure how to make the lists more readable besides having them in separate files too. Outputting to a file is required as i need the postcode labels stored in someway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your comparison block isn't working is that when you use csv reader to read your file, each line is being added to `your_list` as a `list`.  So you are making a list of lists and when you compare those things it doesn't match.

```
['LL58'] == 'LL58'    # fails
```

So, inspect your_list and see what I mean.  You should make a shell `your_list` before you read the file and `append` each new reading to it.  Then inspect that to make sure it looks good.  It would also behoove you to use the `strip()` command to strip off whitespace from each item.  I can't recall if csv reader does that automatically.

Also...  a better structure for testing for membership is to use sets instead of lists.  `in` will work for lists, but it is MUCH faster for sets, so I would put your comparison items into `sets`.

Lastly, it isn't clear what you are trying to do with `NationalPostcodes2`.  Just use your NationalPostcodes, but put them in a set with `{}`.

Comment: Hi Jeff,

Thank you very much for your detailed response, it has been very helpful

I will now use `sets`, something I wasn't aware of before!

and `NationalPostcodes2` was originally in place to remove duplicates from `NationalPostcodes` which i had input originally by mistake

Comment: @Templar a couple of other things you might want to consider.  What you have is fine, but you could tweak your design a bit.  You could do things "on the fly" when reading an not even capture things in `your_list`.  Think about how you might do that.  Then, if the mind isn't blown, you could also get rid of `my_list` and write your outputs "on the fly" as well.  Consider those design patterns...  It won't make any noticeable performance difference for small/medium size things, but if you had to ingest a massive amount of input, it could clean up and speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeff H's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60211000/982257) is correct, but for what it's worth here's how I might write this code (untested):

```
# Note: Since, as you wrote, these are only single-column files I did not use the csv
# module, as it will just add additional unnecessary overhead.

# Read the known data from files--this will always be more flexible and maintainable than
# hard-coding them in your code.  This is just one possible scheme for doing this; e.g.
# you could also put all of them into a single JSON file
standard_postcode_files = {
    'HywelDDA': 'hyweldda.csv',
    'NationalPostcodes': 'nationalpostcodes.csv',
    'UKPostcodes': 'ukpostcodes.csv'
}

def read_postcode_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        # exclude blank lines and strip additional whitespace
        return [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]

standard_postcodes = {}
for key, filename in standard_postcode_files.items():
    standard_postcodes[key] = set(read_postcode_file(filename))

# Assuming all post codes are unique to a set, map postcodes to the set they belong to
postcodes_reversed = {v: k for k, s in standard_postcodes.items() for v in s}

your_postcodes = read_postcode_file('postcodes.csv')

labels = [postcodes_reversed[code] for code in your_postcodes]

with open('DiscretisedPostCodes.csv', 'w') as f:
    for label in labels:
        f.write(label + '\n')
```

I would probably do other things like not make the input filename hard-coded.  If you need to work with multiple columns using the `csv` module would also be fine with minimal additional changes, but since you're just writing one item per line I figured it was unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you Iguananaut, this is very insightful!